# Modifying environment vspace

Tags: spacing, environments, friggeri-cv

I am editing the Friggeri-CV template in ShareLaTeX, but I want to modify the `\vspace` for a particular entry list (and keep it as `\parsep` for the other cases). Is there any way to do this other than creating another environment for it?

```
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\newenvironment{entrylist}{%
  \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}ll }
}{%
  \end{tabular*}
}
\renewcommand{\bfseries}{\headingfont\color{headercolor}}
\newcommand{\entry}[4]{%
  #1&\parbox[t]{11.8cm}{%
    \textbf{#2}%
    \hfill%
    {\footnotesize\addfontfeature{Color=lightgray} #3}\\%
    #4\vspace{\parsep}%
  }\\}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! `\vspace` is not an environment but macro for vertical distance: `\vspace{<lenght>}`. If I correctly understand your question you only need replace `\vspace{\parsep}` with `\vspace{<desired length>}`.

Comment: You could redefine `\entrylist` to take an optional argument and have it set `\parsep` to the default, if there's no optional value given, or set it to whatever value is passed, if there is one.  I don't know if this is a good idea as I don't know the class/package. I can't test as you've not provided usable code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default `\parsep` in [ShareLaTeX](http://www.sharelatex.com)'s [Fancy CV](https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/cv-or-resume/fancy-cv) is `5.0pt plus 2.0pt`. One can save-and-restore it around `entrylist`:

```
\newlength{\parsepsave}
\setlength{\parsepsave}{\parsep}% Store \parsep
\setlength{\parsep}{<len>}% New/update \parsep
\begin{entrylist}
  \entry ...
  \entry ...
  ...
\end{entrylist}
\setlength{\parsep}{\parsepsave}% Restore \parsep
```

If you want a specific gap between `\entry`'s, then you can issue `\\[<len>]` as needed, since `entrylist` is actually a `tabular`:

[image]

```
\begin{entrylist}
  \entry
    {since 2009}
    {Ph.D. {\normalfont candidate in Computer Science}}
    {DNET/INRIA, LIP/ÉNS de Lyon}
    {\emph{A Quantified Theory of Social Cohesion.}}
  \\[1cm]% <-------------- Insert forced gap
  \entry
    {2007–2008}
    {M.Sc. magna cum laude}
    {IXXI, École Normale Supérieure de Lyon}
    {Majoring in Computer Science\\
    Specialization in Complex Systems}
  ...
\end{entrylist}
```